# The installation process of Ubuntu does not see Windows XP system

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu but it does not see I've got windows xp already installed
and as this is our first time trying Linux we don't want to get rid of xp yet

hoping for a low tech solution or a walkthrough.

Comment: Windows XP doesn't get any updates anymore. I suggest you to get Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already installed Ubuntu? Normally Ubuntu would find your XP and add it to the boot menu automatically if you choose to install Ubuntu to different partition(alongside). Just letting you know, Ubuntu does not show that you have Windows XP distinctively, it can although show you all partitions of your hard drive at one of the very beginning screens of the installation process. On one of your partition XP might exist , so just select or add(create) the new partition to install Ubuntu to. Ubuntu is like others Linux distributions - it is very good at being installed alongside with any Windows.

Comment: I have not installed yet i get to stage of installing and it under heading no operating system detected gives me two paths (delete or other)other looks to be manual partition area at this stage I got scared it would stuff up xp

Comment: Okay, I see, do you have a free unallocated space to create a new partition for Ubuntu? It is can be seen at the screen of manual partitioning. If you don't have free unallocated space, then you need to resize your partition you currently use for Windows XP. It is needed to have done it before process of installation because in there you can not resize - only delete or add/create.

Answer (score 0):

**MBR** partition table (the only partition table supported by Windows XP) allows to use only **4 primary partitions** per disk. If you have all 4 partitions formatted with Windows file systems, you won't be able to install Ubuntu without removing one, as it needs to be installed on a file system that supports **UNIX permission system** and is natively supported by Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Begin the installation process and when you reach the "Installation type" step, click on "Something else"

Resize your Windows XP partition to make some space, and create the following partition:

- partition 1 : SWAP (type : linux-swap; size : same size as your RAM size)
- partition 2 : OS (type : ext4; size : at least 10 GB; mount point : `/`)
- partition 3 : Home (type : ext4; size : what you want; mount point : `/home`)

And select `sda` as place where to install GRUB.

And from here, continue your installation as usual.

In the case that you don't find Windows XP in you GRUB menu after installing Ubuntu, follow this steps :

-> Boot on you LiveCD

-> When you are on the LiveCD Desktop, open a new terminal with `ctrl+alt+T`

-> Type the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair -y
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

-> Launch boot-repair with `sudo boot-repair`

-> Click on "Recommended Repair"

-> Reboot